# Avoid rerendering a layout in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

I have a layout that I'm using in all the routes of my front. The routes are managed using react-router-dom. All is perfect at this point, the issue is when I navigate into different routs, just in that moment the layout (backgroun and navbar) is reload along with the called component. Is notorius a flicker.

*Layout.js*

```
export default function Layout({children}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="App bg-gray-900 h-screen w-screen relative overflow-hidden flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                <SideBar />
                <div className="h-40-r w-40-r bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 rounded-full absolute  left-2/3 -top-56 transform rotate-160 animate-animation"></div>
                <div className="h-35-r w-35-r bg-gradient-to-r from-red-400 via-pink-500 to-purple-500 rounded-full absolute top-96 -left-20 animate-animation "></div>
                {children}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

In this aproach, I'm calling other component in this layout.

*Router.js*

```
export default function AppRouter() {
    return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Index />}/>
                <Route path="/tasks" element={<Tasks />}/>
                <Route path="/test" element={<Test />}/>
            </Routes>
    )
}
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router >  
        <Layout>
          <AppRouter />
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*I don't know if is this file well done*

I'v done some modification trying to get the answer, for insance appliying the layout in every page, controlled the order to the load, but until now without results.

Comment: I can't reproduce any "flickering" issue here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-brown-1j7o2?file=/src/App.js). Perhaps you've not shared enough of your code for us to understand everything it's doing when routes change. `Layout` should remain mounted so the only thing that may "flicker" is the routed components switching out when the old unmounts and the new mounts.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, it was great and take me away to the solution. All with the code is ok, but my bad, I was testing the routes writing it directly in the browser, not using a <Link> tag. Your sandbox opened my eyes about this.

Comment: OK, glad to have helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `<Layout>` outside of `<Router>` in `App.js`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router >  
          <AppRouter />
      </Router>
      <Layout />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
The routes should be tested using a `<Link />` tag. I was testing the routes in the browser.

```
<li>
  <Link to="tasks">Tasks</Link>
</li>
<li>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of children use a router Outlet, this solves rerender issue.

Check [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#index-routes)

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App bg-gray-900 h-screen w-screen relative overflow-hidden flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <SideBar />
        <div className="h-40-r w-40-r bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 rounded-full absolute  left-2/3 -top-56 transform rotate-160 animate-animation"></div>
        <div className="h-35-r w-35-r bg-gradient-to-r from-red-400 via-pink-500 to-purple-500 rounded-full absolute top-96 -left-20 animate-animation "></div>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```